# Ruby on rails bundle install - json error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, installation, linux-mint

I have a lot of difficulties to run Ruby on Rails. Maybe you can tell me where I'm wrong ?
I'm on Linux Mint 17.2, with LAMP local server.

To install Ruby :

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484
$
```

I didn't have to install gem, it works as shown here :

```
$ gem help commands

    GEM commands are:

        build             Build a gem from a gemspec
        cert              Manage RubyGems certificates and signing settings
    (...)
        update            Update the named gems (or all installed gems) in the local
                          repository
        which             Find the location of a library file you can require

    For help on a particular command, use 'gem help COMMAND'.

    Commands may be abbreviated, so long as they are unambiguous.
    e.g. 'gem i rake' is short for 'gem install rake'.

Then I installed rails, I dont remember which of those two ways :

    $ sudo gem install rails

or

    $ sudo apt-get install ruby-railties-4.0

I dont find how to uninstall, so I can't test other ways to install.

Then, I made an application :

        $ rails new (path)/second_app

          create  
          create  README.rdoc
          create  Rakefile
          create  config.ru
          create  .gitignore
          create  Gemfile
          create  app
          create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
          (...)
          create  vendor/assets/javascripts
          create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
          create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
          create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
             run  bundle install
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:308:in `bin_path': can't find gem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:268:in `bundle_command'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:277:in `run_bundle'
        from (eval):1:in `run_bundle'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/cli.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.2/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

It looks like it was a problem running bundle install. According to tutorials, I run the command

```
$ bundle install
```

And I got

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.4.2) 
Using i18n (0.7.0) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
…
Using jbuilder (1.5.3) 
Using jquery-rails (3.1.3) 
Installing json (1.8.3) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /home/alejandro/.bundler/tmp/9377/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/alejandro/.bundler/tmp/9377/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I tryed to install json in several ways :

```
$ sudo gem install json -v '1.8.3'
$ sudo apt-get install json -v '1.8.3'
$ sudo gem install json
```

But it don't work. I tryed to to run de server :

```
$ rails server
Could not find gem 'rails (= 4.0.2) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I have tryed to install rvm and rbenv, but nothing works in the way tutorials says it should. My feeling is that I missed something in the begynning, but I dont know what.

Could you please help me ?

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 1):

You need to update gem lock and all dependency 
For that please execute below command,

**gem update --system**

Now You can install json gem using , 

**gem install json**

Try above command and let me know if you still face same thing. Above things  works fine for me:D

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.